# Rename Equation with subsubsection

Tags: equations, numbering

I' like to rename the equations so:

**chapter.section.subsection,subsubsection.theequation**

I tried with

```
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thesubsubsection.\arabic{equation}}
```

**First Edit:** I use frequently `book` and `article` classes.

But it doesn't function. Why?

Thank you

Comment: Please, avoid adding nonsensical tags. Are you sure you want five numbers?

Comment: Yes, Could I use **chngctnr** package?

Comment: The `chngcntr` package is obsolete; `\counterwithin{equation}{subsection}` is available with no added package. Your readers will not be happy.

Comment: Thank you, but It is not OK, I have 4 numbers, but I want 5 numbers...

Comment: Oh, you want `\counterwithin{equation}{subsubsection}`. Are you sure that everything will be inside a subsubsection? This requires a very rigid format. I can't recommend to.

Comment: Thank you, Same thing of the previous case, Then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `amsmath`'s `\numberwithin` command to number equations within subsubsections.

In an `article` document, you can do as in the following example.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\numberwithin{equation}{subsubsection}
\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\begin{equation}
a^2 + b^2 = c^2
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

In a `book` document, subsubsections are not numbered by default, so you can add `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}` to number them.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\numberwithin{equation}{subsubsection}
\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\begin{equation}
a^2 + b^2 = c^2
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```